# cannot find -lgcc_s

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, gcc

I am attempting to compile a program with g77 and I keep getting the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I saw on another forum that this is related to libgcc, when looking for libgcc I get

```
>find /usr/ -name libgcc*

/usr/share/doc/libgcc1
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libgcc1
/usr/lib/libgccpp.so.1.0.3
/usr/lib/libgccpp.so.1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc_eh.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/libgcc_s_32.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/libgcc_eh.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/32/libgcc_s_32.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/32/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/32/libgcc_eh.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/32/libgcc.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/libgcc.a
/usr/lib/ure/lib/libgcc3_uno.so
```

Comment: I've tried exporting the path to /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6, /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6, and /usr/lib, but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Answer (score 6):

This is because although libgcc is present, it may not be in the paths known to [ldconfig](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/ldconfig/). Check this by doing:

```
sudo /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libgcc
```

Does the output show that the link to libgcc corresponds to paths that you have listed above?

A workaround for you may be to add the link to the relevant library to your compile command [e.g.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1750758)

```
g++ program.cpp -L /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/
```

Another solution may be to create a symbolic link to the library yourself.

```
 ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc_s.so /usr/lib/gcc/libgcc_s.so
```

Comment: In response to 'sudo /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libgcc' I got ' libgccpp.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgccpp.so.1
 libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1'. Tried with those paths, but no luck. tried with symbolic link but no luck with that either.

Comment: Also, I'm using g77 to compile

Comment: `sudo` is not needed for `ldconfig -p`

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2007/10/how-to-add-shared-libraries-to-linuxs.html

Create a new file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` called `.conf`

Edit the file and add a line per directory of shared libraries (`*.so` files), it will look something like:

```
/usr/lib/APPLICATION/lib
```

Reload the list of system-wide library paths:

```
sudo ldconfig
```