# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: 17.10, gcc, make

I am trying to install a software in my 64 bit Ubuntu 17.10 system. But every time the `make all` command fails, stating the following error message.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Kindly help me by providing a solution to this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably duplicate https://askubuntu.com/questions/346377/cannot-find-lgcc-s

Comment: To get a better diagnosis, please [edit] your question to include information about the software you are trying to build and a larger fragment of the error output

Answer (score 0):

You can install with

```
sudo apt-get install libgcc1 lib32gcc1 libx32gcc1
```

And for successful compilation of other stuff install build-essential:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake libtool
```

Comment: Sir, these packages are already installed with new version. But the issue didn't solved.

Comment: Which program are you trying to build and for which CPU architecture? Do you use cross-compilation?

Comment: I am trying to install RadWare software with amd 64 arch. And yes I'm using  cross-compiling, but I guess it's not working. Kindly help.