# Finding -lgcc_s

Tags: 18.04, compiling, libraries, makefile

I'm trying to install a program that seems to use `libgcc_s.so`. After implementing the possible remedies suggested in the SO:[LINK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346377/cannot-find-lgcc-s), I still can't figure out why the compiler fails to find it.

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have `libgcc_s.so` at these locations:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/x32/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/32/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/32/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/libgcc_s.so
```

I have created a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc_s.so /usr/lib/gcc/libgcc_s.so
```

But, I still get the same error. I'm using g77 compiler on a Ubuntu 18.04 OS. How can I amend the makefile to help it find the necessary file?

Comment: Which program are you trying to install? Is it 32-bit or 64?

Comment: The issue got resolved after changing the compiler to `gfortran`.